# VSCode settings for json file - remove braces formatting

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

VSCode default autoformatter is formatting .json files with empty objects to a single line, which is not what i want. Basically i try to get away from this:

```
  "settings": {}
```

To this:

```
"settings": {
}
```

Here is my settings.json file in VSCode[image]

Comment: look in the settings of the JSON formatter

Comment: Thanks! I have checked the vscode settings below but there is no reference of this. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json

Comment: but does the formatter have any settings of what to do/don't

Comment: That is kind of what i ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting `JSON > Format: Keep Lines` , if enabled, will do what you want.

```
Keep all existing new lines when formatting.
```

It will preserve your newline between the braces upon formatting.

Comment: you're a star! thank you